# Define table width & height in CSS, so it has a specific width/height ratio when printed

Tags: html, css, printing, html-table

I have a table on my webpage, that uses a specific print CSS, that removes all the web site elements so that it can be printed on posters.

What I do is:

1. Visit the page with Google Chrome,
2. Click: File -> Print -> "Print using system dialog...",
3. Click PDF -> "Save as PostScript", and
4. Process with Adobe Distiller (150 dpi & 18” x 24”).

Since I want my table to fill the 18"x24" (18/24 = 3/4) poster nicely, how can I make sure that its width/height aspect ration is 3/4, without putting in specific dimensions that would come to bite me in print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, the only solution that came to my head is the one where you'd have to wrap the table with two additional `div`s.

> Here's the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NmAJ8/)**

As we speak, I'm trying to improve the solution to get rid of the divs.

At the moment I'm using one div as a `wrapper` with width set to 100%, then inside of it there is another div (`innerWrapper`) which is positioned absolutely and spread to the `wrapper`'s dimensions. To set the div's *height* I used a simple trick - added a pseudo `:after` element to the `wrapper` which has `padding-bottom` set to 133%. Padding percentage values are inherited from parent's `width` (yes!). In case of somebody asking - we can't ommit the `innerWrapper` div and set its style directly to `table` becuase `top, right, bottom, left` method won't work for it (neither `width` and `height` set to `100%`). Divs are `block` elements, tables have `display: table`.
Whole code looks like this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="innerWrapper">
        <table></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#wrapper {
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    padding-bottom: 133%;
}
#innerWrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```